# Which AD&D (likely from 2e) book contained stats for Fionn mac Cumhaill, and possibly a class conversion from 1e to 2e?

Tags: product-identification, adnd-2e

I recently reacquired TSR's *Celts Campaign Sourcebook* for AD&D 2nd ed because I wanted to reread some parts I *thought* were in that book. After reading the copy I found, however, I don't see the information I expected. I don't know if there are multiple printings of this book, or if the information I'm looking for is in one or more other books. IIRC both pieces of information are Celtic-flavored, so I'm surprised I'm not seeing them in *Celts*.

The first piece of information was a statblock for Irish legendary hero Fionn mac Cumhaill. If my memory is correct he was statted as a Druid, and probably a dual-class Druid plus something (likely Fighter, but I'm inferring that instead of remembering it). He may have had *Dimension Door* or a similar ability. This book may have come out before 2nd edition's *Tome of Magic* was published, as *Tome* contained elemental wizards and I had been thinking of trying to make a Fionn-like character using elemental wizardry when I discovered he already had a stat block.

The second, more hazily remembered information (which might even be in a different book from the first piece of information) involved adapting a class (I'm pretty sure it was Bard) from 1st to 2nd edition. I remember this because the proposed Bard class had curses, which the 2nd ed PHB Bard did not. The Bard in the *Celts Campaign Sourcebook* **does** have curse abilities, but I think I remember notes on converting a 1st edition class to 2nd edition, and I can't find that in my copy of *Celts*.

Do either or both of the above pieces of information ring any bells, and if so, do you know what books they appeared in?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### DMGR5 *Creative Campaigning* (1993)

*Creative Campaigning* has stats for Fionn MacCumhail as an 18th level Warrior/8th level Druid. It used a similar style of book cover and interior design to *Celts* and came out around the same time.

Comment: I suppose I should have asked about the two different remembered entries separately, since they could very well be in two different books.

I'm trying to get a copy of creative campaigning. I appreciate this answer as it looks like a great resource with lessons I can apply in other additions!

Comment: @mkdir I don't know the source for the bard 1e to 2e conversion, though it sounds like something that might have run in Dragon magazine.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have Dragon, but some friends did, so it's certainly a possibility.